# Obtengo undefined en mis variables de entorno de React

Tags: reactjs

Cargo el archivo **`.env`** e intento mostrar dos variables, pero solo se muestra una, quiero saber la razón de esto.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import './App.css';

dotenv.config();

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div> 
        PROBANDO
        {console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_KEY_PRUEBA)}
        {console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_KEY)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Las variable dentro del .env están asi

```
REACT_APP_KEY = PROBANDO ESTA COSA;
REACT_APP_KEY_PRUEBA = PROBANDO;
```

El resultado que obtuve fue este:

```
undefined
PROBANDO ESTA COSA
```

Comment: ¿Porqué añades un signo de punto y coma (`;`) a tus líneas del archivo `.env`? ¿Porqué agregas esos espacios en blanco entre el nombre de la variable, el valor y el signo de asignación (`=`)? La [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) de `dotenv` indica que cada variable de entorno ha de guardarse en una línea diferente (sin punto y coma o ningún otro carácter de finalización) y en el formato: `variable=valor`, sin dejar espacios en blanco alrededor del signo de asignación (`=`). Saludos

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. lei la documentación. aprendi algo nuevo . aunque en este caso descubrí que el problema era porque en una carpeta yo tenia otro package json y en la carpeta raiz también tenia un package.json lo que hice fue borrar el package.json de la otra carpeta y dejar el de la raiz y agregarle la ruta donde estaba mi  express. nose porque anteriormente lo había hecho asi pero ese fue el problema

Comment: reinicia el proyecto, ctrl + c   y volve a levantar tu proyecto